# Connecting to SQL Server Database using PHP 5.5 Connection error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Ok so i have managed to get the drivers installed and have copied and pasted a connection test php from a website. This is the code:

```
<?php
$hostname = '(LocalDb)\v11.0';
$connection_options = array('Database'=>'MagicFountainMedia2014', 'UID'=>'home\SQL', 'PWD'=>'');
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($hostname, $connection_options);
if(!is_resource($conn)){ echo 'Could not connect: '; var_dump(sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL)); exit(0); }
echo 'Connection established successfully.';
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

I have altered the appropriate variables (as far as I can tell) but when I run the PHP on my apache server (XAMMP) it dumps this in the browser:

```
Could not connect: array(2) { [0]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(5) "28000" ["SQLSTATE"]=> string(5) "28000" [1]=> int(18456) ["code"]=> int(18456) [2]=> string(87) "[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'home\SQL'." ["message"]=> string(87) "[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'home\SQL'." } [1]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(5) "28000" ["SQLSTATE"]=> string(5) "28000" [1]=> int(18456) ["code"]=> int(18456) [2]=> string(87) "[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'home\SQL'." ["message"]=> string(87) "[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'home\SQL'." } }
```

Does anyone have any idea whats gone wrong? It would be a massive help as!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you read the error message? the login failed. e.g. wrong username, wrong password, or both.

Comment: The way I read the error message was that it had failed to log in but I didn't see anything specifically stated what was wrong. I assumes it is just stating the for some reason all the credentials failed not a specific one. Am I interpreting the error message wrong? @MarcB

Comment: You have a username with no password - that's not going to get you very far. If you removed it because of security for this posting that's fine... if you're attempting to use windows authentication this way you're going to fail every time. Let us know which one you are attempting.